# vertical centering not working with flexbox

Tags: html, css

This is my html file

```
<nav id="navbar">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    
<section id="welcome-section">
  <h1>Hey I am human</h1>
  <p>A web Developer</p>
</section>
```

This is my css code

```
body, html{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
nav{
  background-color:#333;
}
nav ul{
  list-style:none;
  display:flex;
  flex-flow:row nowrap;
  justify-content:flex-end;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
nav ul li:hover{
  background-color:green;
}
nav ul li a{
  text-decoration:none;
  padding:1rem;
  text-align:center;
  color:white;
  display:block;
}

/*WELCOME SECTION*/
#welcome-section{
  display:flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  align-items: center;
  text-align:center;
  background-color:green;
  width:100%; 
  height:35rem;
}
```

I am having trouble centering  h1 and p vertically which are in section. I tried flexbox but no luck. I don't know why its not working. I am trying to make it look like this codepen:
[Portfolio Page](https://codepen.io/freeCodeCamp/full/zNBOYG)

Answer (score 1):

Add `justify-content: center;` to welcome-section;
See working example here: https://jsfiddle.net/8uwrkqv7/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `align-items: center;` use `justify-content: center;` in id **#welcome-section**.
Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Use `justify-content:center;` in `#welcome-section {}`
`align-items: center;` won't work.